# Why if condition giving same out put on success or unsucess?

Tags: shell

I have a script named `temp.sh`. I am running it from another script like...

```
sh temp.sh | tr '|' '\n' > sel-employee
count=`wc -l sel-employee`

if [ '$count' == 0 ] ; then 
echo "ERROR"
else
echo "SUCCESS"
fi
```

when I run this script if file  sel-employee has zero line OR more then zero line in both cases it is output  SUCCESS. I can not understand why?

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ '$count' == 0 ] ; then
```

The variable `count` isn't expanded because it's in *single* quotes. Use double-quotes: `"$count"`. The string `$count` is different from the string `0`, so the comparison is always false. Run the script with `sh -x` to see the commands that shell runs. Also, you should use `=`, not `==`, the latter is not standard and doesn't work in all shells.